# Disable Cellular data for ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, plist, nsurlconnection

Is it possible to implement something like disabling the cellular data for a particular application (for ios version < 7, I know there is a feature like this in iOS 7 Cellular data).

One solution may be to have a Boolean switch in your app preference to enable/disable 3G, and check Reachability class for the connection Type and then make the HTTP Requests. I am looking for something like a config/permission in plist or something that would block the cellular data or any other easier alternative. Any idea ??

Answer (score 1):

Using [Reachability](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class, you can choose the wifi only connection, and that way you disable the cellular data:

Use this function to check if wifi is on

```
- (BOOL)isWifiOn {
    Reachability* wifiReach = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];

    NetworkStatus netStatus = [wifiReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    return (netStatus==ReachableViaWiFi);
}
```

similar code can be used to check reachabilityForInternetConnection but you have to check

```
(netStatus==ReachableViaWiFi)
```

if you care that it's over wifi AND

```
(netStatus==ReachableViaWWAN)
```

if you care that it's over WWAN